# How To Delay Post On Geeklist

Tags: linkedin, twitter-integration, geeklist

If I put a post on Geeklist (which is then posted to Twitter and/or LinkedIn), is there any way to delay the posting?

Comment: Thanks @Fogest.  I would have tagged it with geeklist myself but there was no such tag when I submitted the question.

Comment: No problem. You just do not have enough rep to create a new tag so I created it. In the future you will be able to add the tag now :)